# when deployed python Flask on heroku, there is a H10 error

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I tried to build a Flaks code to Heroku but it failed.
[image]

This code can run at my local server but it went wring on the heroku.
I do not know why.
This is the error message.
Can anyone suggest me what's wrong?

```
     2021-08-10T04:41:36.856280+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-08-10T04:41:36.918818+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-08-10T04:41:42.385210+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=eftw-one-wallet.herokuapp.com request_id=4255991b-48b0-46b4-9a0e-7b10b359c3f6 fwd="209.120.209.75" dyno=web.1 connect=5000ms service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

This is my python Code.

```
    from flask import Flask,jsonify,request
from flask import jsonify
from flask_restful import Api,Resource



app=Flask(__name__)
api=Api(app)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return jsonify({"Message":"It works!"})
@app.route("/<int:number>")
def incrementer(number):
    return "Incremented number is " + str(number+1)
@app.route('/<string:name>/') #https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-restful-apis-using-flask-and-python-655bad51b24
def hello(name):
    return "Hello " + name
@app.route('/person/')
def person():
    return jsonify({'name':'Jimit','address':'India'})

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {"hello world"}



if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you explained more, because H10 errors are usually caused due to Procfile issues, so look into that.

Check this out for more information regarding H10 errors on heroku :
https://dev.to/lawrence_eagles/causes-of-heroku-h10-app-crashed-error-and-how-to-solve-them-3jnl